# Prove that $A/mA \cong A_m/mR_m A_m$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, localization

Let $R$ be a ring and $m$ be a maximal ideal.

$m R_m$ denotes the unique maximal ideal of the localization $R_m$ of $R$ at $m$. Let $A$ be an $R$-module. The localization of $A$ at $m$ is denoted by $A_m$.

> I have to prove that the map $\pi : A \rightarrow A_m, a \mapsto \frac{a}{1}$ induces an isomorphism $A/mA \cong A_m/mR_m A_m$. (*)

My approach : I have shown that $\pi : R \rightarrow R_m, r \mapsto \frac{r}{1}$ induces an isomorphism $R/mR \cong R_m / mR_m$. 
Since the notion of localization of a ring can be generalized to the localization of a module, I think I can directly conclude that (*) holds.

Is my approach correct or is there still something to prove ?

Comment: Why not just try the mapping $A\rightarrow A_m/mA_m$, and show (1) it is surjective, and (2) the kernel is $mA$? By the way, if you think of localization as tensoring with $R_m$, then this is just associativity of the tensor product: $A/mA\cong A\otimes R/m \otimes R_m\cong A\otimes  R_m\otimes R/m\cong A_m/mA_m$.

Comment: @Steve D Thank you for your comment ! You are right that I can just prove the same for $A \rightarrow A_m /mA_m$, but my lecturer recommended to prove first the statement for rings and then to draw a conclusion for modules.  The tip to use associativity of tensor products is great. I don´t know much about tensor products and I hope that I will learn more about it in future courses.

Comment: Look at his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2866499/54738).