# An isomorphism between the residue field and the fraction field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1_A$. Set $X=Spec(A)$. For $x\in X$, let $j_x$ be the corresponding prime ideal.

I have already understood and proved the following claims:

1) $A-j_x$ is a multiplicative set of $A$ at $j_x$.

Then, let $A_x$ be the localization of $A$ with the multiplicative set $A-j_x$. Also I proved:

2) $A_x$ is a local ring with the unique maximal ideal:

$$M_x=A_x - \{ \frac{a}{s} \vert a \in j_x \ \text{and} \ s\in A-j_x \}$$

I also verified: 3) $M_x=j_xA_x$.

Using the universal property of fraction fields, now I have tried to prove that:

$$A_x/M_x \cong Frac(A/j_x)$$

I couldn't have done yet. Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Where exactly is your difficulty? Is it in producing a map between both objects, or checking that it's an isomorphism? If you include the work that you've done in the post, you will get better answers.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2866499) for the proof of a more general statement (put $\mathfrak a=\mathfrak p=j_x$).