# Localization of the polynomial ring at a prime ideal modulo maximal ideal is isomorphic to polynomial ring modulo prime ideal.

Tags: ideals, irreducible-polynomials, localization

Let $p \in K[T]$ irreducible, s.t. $\text{LC}(p) = 1$. Then
$$ K[T]/(p) \cong K[T]_{(p)}/pK[T]_{(p)}.$$

What I have is:
\begin{align*}
&K[T] \hookrightarrow K[T]_{(p)} \text{ and } K[T]_{(p)} \twoheadrightarrow K[T]_{(p)}/pK[T]_{(p)}\\
& \implies K[T] \overset{f}\longrightarrow K[T]_{(p)}/pK[T]_{(p)}
\end{align*}
The kernel of $f$ is $(p)$ so
$$ K[T]/(p) \cong \text{im} f = \left\{g + pK[T]_{(p)} \mid g \in K[T] \right\} \overset{?} = K[T]_{(p)}/pK[T]_{(p)}.$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2866499/54738) for a more general statement.

Comment: As I don't have enough reputation, I have ask here. How can $A \to A_\mathfrak{p}$ be surjective in your post?

Comment: It's no surjective, but it's a ring *epimorphism* in the sense of category theory.

Comment: Ok unfortunately I don't have any knowledge about category theory. Perhaps you can help me without category theory?

Comment: Yes; to understand the proof you need to know only this fact: given $\lambda:A\to A_{\mathfrak p} $ and two ring homorphisms, $\alpha,\beta:A_{\mathfrak p}\to Y $, if $\alpha\circ\lambda=\beta\circ\lambda $ then $\alpha=\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\overline{\frac{r}{s}} \in K[T]_{(p)}/(p)K[T]_{(p)}$. Then
\begin{align*}
   p \not | s &\implies \exists a,b \in K[T]: ap + bs = 1\\
& \implies bs = 1 - ap\\
& \implies f(bs) = \overline{bs} = 1 + (p)K[T]_{(p)}\\
& \implies f(rb) =f(r) f(b) \equiv \overline{\frac{r}{s}} 
\end{align*}
Hence
$$ \text{im } f = K[T]_{(p)}/(p)K[T]_{(p)}.$$